# Given the number of total nodes and degrees of each node, is it possible to construct a graph?

Tags: python, graph, graph-theory, polyhedra, planar-graph

Take the cube as an example, there are **8** nodes and **12** edges, and each node is connected with **3** nodes.

With [networkx](https://networkx.org/), I must input all the edges manually.  For example, the following code is to construct a graph containing all the edges of an icosahedron (12 nodes, 30 edges, 5 adjacent nodes per node).

```py
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
nodes = list(range(12))
edges = [
    [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [0, 5],
    [1, 2], [1, 6], [1, 10], [1, 5],
    [2, 3], [2, 6], [2, 7],
    [3, 4], [3, 7], [3, 8],
    [4, 5], [4, 8], [4, 11], 
    [5, 11], [5, 10],
    [6, 7], [6, 9], [6, 10],
    [7, 8], [7, 9],
    [8, 9], [8, 11],
    [9, 10], [9, 11],
    [10, 11],
]
G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
G.add_edges_from(edges)
```

My question is **how to get all the possible edges without writing them manually.** The name of every node can be randomly initialized.

To the best of my knowledge, the Erdős–Rényi model in [igraph](https://igraph.org/python/) cannot constrain the adjacent nodes.

```py
from igraph import *

g = Graph.Erdos_Renyi(12, m=30, directed=False)
g.get_edgelist()
"""
[(0, 1),
 (0, 2),
 (1, 3),
 (2, 3),
 (0, 4),
 (1, 4),
 (3, 5),
 (4, 6),
 (5, 6),
 (0, 7),
 (2, 7),
 (3, 7),
 (6, 7),
 (0, 8),
 (1, 8),
 (3, 8),
 (0, 9),
 (3, 9),
 (4, 9),
 (6, 9),
 (0, 10),    node10 has more than 5 edges.
 (2, 10),
 (3, 10),
 (5, 10),
 (7, 10),
 (8, 10),
 (1, 11),
 (2, 11),
 (4, 11),
 (9, 11)]
"""
```

Comment: I think the number of nodes and the degrees of each node is not sufficient to create a unique graph.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks for your kindful comment. The relative number of nodes does not matter. In this case, can I construct a graph by the number of nodes and degrees of each node? For example, 4 nodes and degree=2 can construct a square, and degree=3 can construct a tetrahedron.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a unique planar graph only knowing the number of vertices, edges, and edges-per-vertex. A simple counter example:

Take your cube example with 8 vertices, 12 edges and 3 edges-per vertex then you can have:

```
[
  (A,B),(B,C),(C,D),(D,A), # top face of the cube.
  (E,F),(F,G),(G,H),(H,E), # bottom face of the cube.
  (A,E),(B,F),(C,G),(D,H)  # sides of the cube connecting top and bottom.
]
```

This makes a planar graph with 6 faces where every face has 4 edges.

You can equally have:

```
[
  (A,B),(B,C),(C,D),(D,E),(E,F),(F,G),(G,H),(H,A), # cycle containing all vertices
  (A,C), # connect vertices 2 apart on the cycle.
  (B,D), # overlap previous and also connect vertices 2 apart on the cycle.
  (E,G), # connect vertices 2 apart on the cycle.
  (F,H)  # overlap previous and also connect vertices 2 apart on the cycle.
]
```

This creates a planar graph with 4 triangular faces and 2 faces bounded by 6 edges.